# Android Vibrator not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a test app where `Vibrator` is not working.
I am using **Nexus S** to run this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_vibrate);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d("me", "onClick");
             Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             if(vibrator.hasVibrator()){
                 vibrator.vibrate(300);
                 Log.d("me","has Vibrator");
             }
        }
    });

}
}
```

and I get the logs as

```
D/me      ( 1552): onClick
D/me      ( 1552): has Vibrator
```

But the same code works fine with android 2.3.6

Comment: Have you specified permission in the Manifest file?

Comment: @Dya : ya i have specfied     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Comment: Add the permission as the guys above mentioned. Also I noticed that if you choose a too short vibration time, it doesnt vibrate at all. 300 should be enough though.

Comment: @Ascorbin, but the strange is its working fine with 2.3

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3109792/735675

Comment: @Dya,  stackoverflow.com/a/3109792/73567 this link didnt help me, i tried even giving the length 3000 still no use

Comment: strange differences within Android :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MainAcitivty.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: thanks for ans, I tried still id doesn't work, but it works with android 2.3

Comment: Try removing the condition check also. Just to try although I don't think that's causing the problem..